# QT Creator .ui file and page when run programs are different

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying make some design changes on
[QT Serial Monitor](https://github.com/mich-w/QtSerialMonitor)

application

When I try to remove and rename buttons or other things, I can not see changes when I run the program. Do I need build/run ui first or what should I do?

Comment: Try to clear the file "ui_<yourclass>.h" inside your project folder in order to force the system to recompile your .ui file.

Comment: This usually happens if you did an insource build first, and then switched to an out-of-source build later without cleaning the build artifacts from the source folder first. Or someone accidentally submitted `ui_*.h` files from an insource build to the repository